# Joining csv with shapefile using Python

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-joins

I am wanting to join a csv with an shp file any ideas on the methods used to complete this.

I've seen a few different ways none of which are working for me?

Comment: Why do you want to use the python for something like that?

Comment: Could you [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/339098/edit) your question to include the code snippets you tried please? This would help to re-open your question.

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to use a virtual layer with Python:

```
query = "?query=Select shapefile.*, csv.* from shapefile join csv on shapefile.commonfield = csv.commonfield;"
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer( query, , "joined layer", "virtual" )
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

shapefile is your shapelayer and csv your CSV-table